# Real-Time Data Recording Speed / Performance / Delay

Tags: c#

**The Context**
I have written a piece of software that reads online market data in real-time, and writes it down to disk. Each security is written in a single file, via Multi-threaded Custom Queued Background Workers.

Worker_Q_Security_A > File_A (Append)
Market Data   >  Worker_Q_Security_B > File_B (Append)
                          Worker_Q_Security_C > File_C (Append)

A worker instance is created for each message and queued, to take the load off the Real-Time Reader and to avoid a bottle-neck at that level.

**The Issue**
What happens now is that, as the volume of data grows, **I am receiving data faster that I am writing it**. This results in the Workers Queues Growing, and the written data is delayed more and more.

What advice could help improve speed performance, making it possible to write faster, whith low delay and avoid bottlenecks at the writing workers levels ?

**EDIT** : 
I am using a customized version of Pooya Khamooshi's [QueuedBackgroudWorker](http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.fr/2009/11/create-thread-safe-queued.html)
I have no Idea on how to design an architecture capable of delegating the tick writing to a threaded system by arrival order, and avoid to create one worker for each tick.

Comment: It seems slightly odd that disk would be a bigger bottleneck than network, but if you are simply appending a bunch of bytes to disk and doing nothing else, then disk *is* the bottleneck and you cannot do anything about it (apart from RAID0-ing several SSDs). But can you elaborate the "A worker instance is created for each message and queued" part? Does this mean you are creating a new thread each time? What about **resource monitor**? Is CPU the bottleneck, or is it your disk? What's the network receive rate? When you have answers to all these questions, then you can consider refactoring.

Comment: For example, simply increasing a `StreamWriter`'s buffer size would allow data to be written in larger chunks, which would increase throughput due to larger contiguous writes. This will, of course, slightly increase latency.

Comment: @Groo : Yes, I am creating a new thread each time, and put it into a worker Queue. I did not find another way to handle this because the writing sohould be done in Parallel as the program needs to do other stuff with the data, that can't wait for the data to be written. I don't think the CPU is the bottleneck as it is used by 30% only. What happened now is that I stopped live data reception, and the workers are still writing data received more than one hour ago

Comment: @Groo Increasing latency is precisely what I want to avoid at this point. Not sure that increasing StreamWriter's buffer size would be of real help here (need to check, though)

Comment: Are you creating a thread per tick? Why not buffer the ticks into an in-memory representation of the file then write that down once it reaches a certian number of records? that would dramatically cut down your disk access.

Comment: @Mika: and how large are these data packets in bytes? Note that creating a new thread adds a **lot** of CPU and memory overhead: To create a thread, a kernel object is allocated and initialized, the thread's stack memory (**1MB of memory per thread!**) is allocated and initialized, and OS sends every DLL in the process a DLL_THREAD_ATTACH notification, causing pages from disk to be **faulted into memory** so that code can execute. This is why `ThreadPool` exists, and, even better, .NET 4 `Task`s.

Comment: @Chris: that's what a `StreamWriter` already does under the hood, depending on its buffer size. If you don't explicitly flush it, it will only flush the entire buffer to disk when it's full.

Comment: @Chris Yes, you are right. We did this at first but experienced Memory Issues and decided to put that aside to tackle it. I'll give it a shot Back. The right question would be, what is the "ideal" size for that buffer in order to have a fair tradeoff. I'll try to calibrate it empirically to start with

Comment: @Groo. Oooh Nice one concerning the StreamBuffer mechanism. Did not know about these details. I'll give it a shot and let you know later

Comment: @Groo please see edit. I don't see how .Net 4 Task could diminish the number of workers, would you give me some more precisions to put me on Track ?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't actually create a new thread on each call to `RunAsync`, but merely adds a delegate to a queue for later execution. But it also doesn't appear to be thread-safe because queue operations are not synchronized (locked). Can you specify what you modified about this code?

Comment: But this part is a bit strange: If you say that "workers are still writing data received more than one hour ago", and you have a really lousy HDD writing at 1MB/s (WD Velociraptor can write 4kB chunks at 10MBps, for example, but you can use Resource monitor in Vista/7 to check actual speed/queue depth), this means you **at least 3.6GB** of data in your RAM at this point (but in reality, a lot more due to objects overhead). This means you are running a 64bit .NET process? And it also means that you are able to receive data from the remote server at **1MB/s**. This is also a respectable speed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12497/discussion-between-mika-jacobi-and-groo)